# How to perform Multi Device Tests on Android using the Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to launch my app on multiple mobile devices (emulators) using Robot Framework with Appium.

I am using below keyword in different test cases.But still its launching app on one device only which comes first in the connected list :

```
${appium1}=  Open Application    
...                 http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    
...                 platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}    
...                 platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}  
...                 deviceName= emulator-5556        
...                 appPackage=${appPackage}        
...                 appActivity=${appActivity} 

${appium2}=  Open Application    
...                 http://localhost:4725/wd/hub    
...                 platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}    
...                 platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}    
...                 deviceName=emulator-5554        
...                 appPackage=${appPackage}    
...                 appActivity=${appActivity}
```

Please help me on Multi device testing using Robot Framwork-Appium

Comment: @SangwinGawande  Please reformat the code to use the code markup for the code. Posting it as a quote makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question is not properly formatted , i am pasting sample code which will launch the app on two  devices , you can take reference from here

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    This script starts apps on two phones
Library           AppiumLibrary
Library          Collections

*** Variables ***
${APPIUM_SERVER1}    http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
${APPIUM_SERVER2}    http://0.0.0.0:4750/wd/hub


*** Test cases ***
Test
    setup and open android phone1
    setup and open android phone2

*** Keywords ***
setup and open android phone1
    ${androiddriver1}=    Open Application    ${APPIUM_SERVER1}    platformName=android    platformVersion=7.0    deviceName=f1232233    automationName=uiautomator2
    ...    appPackage=com.samsung.android.contacts    newCommandTimeout=2500    appActivity=com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity
    Set Suite Variable    ${androiddriver1}

setup and open android phone2
    ${androiddriver2}=    Open Application    ${APPIUM_SERVER2}    platformName=android    platformVersion=7.0    deviceName=s12333   automationName=uiautomator2
    ...    appPackage=com.samsung.android.contacts   newCommandTimeout=2500    appActivity=com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity    noReset=True
    Set Suite Variable    ${androiddriver2}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it works. Only i need to provide udid for specific mobile then only it launch app on both the devices.

Comment: Followup question : Once the app is launched on multiple android devices. How we can execute same test cases on multiple mobile devices at once ? As i am having bunch of test cases to execute on multiple android devices. I am trying to use For Loop by passing udid OR Appium Server name  in Test cases,but its not working.It executes test case on single device only.Is there any way using which we can execute test cases (same test cases) on multiple devices at once?

Comment: If u found above answer useful..plz upvote and close it