# FAIL : TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not unicode Robotframework

Tags: android, python, appium, robotframework

When I am trying to Run Appium RobotframeWork, I'm getting above error

My Sample Code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AppiumLibrary

     Test Cases
        AB
        Open Application 
        ...    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
        ...    platformName=Android
        ...    platformVersion=8.0.0
        ...    deviceName=emulator-5554
        ...    appPackage=com.grabqpons.android
        ...    appActivity=com.grabqpons.android.MainActivity

        Sleep    2s
        Click Button    xpath=//*[startswith(@id,'slide-skip-btn')]
        Sleep    2s
```

Response:

```
**Starting test: Sai.AB**

20180118 16:30:17.961 :  INFO : Slept 2 seconds
20180118 16:30:19.276 :  INFO : </td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">
<a href="appium-screenshot-1.png"><img src="appium-screenshot-1.png" width="800px"></a>
20180118 16:30:19.277 :  FAIL : TypeError: exceptions must be old-style 
classes or derived from BaseException, not unicode
Ending test:   Sai.AB
```

Comment: did you get chance to look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167276/how-to-perform-multi-device-tests-on-android-using-the-robot-framework/48168090?noredirect=1#comment83534551_48168090  this have all the necessary information to run your appium test in RF

Comment: I am getting same error